# Unable to open a Python subprocess in Web2py (SIGABRT)

Tags: python, web2py, subprocess

I've got an Apache2/web2py server running using the wsgi handler functionality.  Within one of the controllers, I am trying to run an external executable to perform some processing on 2 files.

My approach to this is to use the `subprocess` module to kick off the executable.  I have simplified the code to a bare-bones implementation with little success.

```
from subprocess import *
p = Popen(("echo", "Hello"), shell=False)
ret = p.wait()
print "Process ended with status %s" % ret
```

When running the above code on its own (create new file and running via python command line), it works exactly as expected.

However, as soon as I place the exact same code into my web2py controller, the external process stops working.  Instead of the process returning with code **0** as is expected in the above example, it always returns **-6** and "Hello" is not printed to `stdout`.

After doing some digging, I found that negative results from `p.wait()` implies that a signal caused the process to end abnormally.  And, according to some docs I found, -6 corresponds to the `SIGABRT` signal.

I would have expected this signal to be a result of some poorly executed code in my child process.  *However*, since this is *only* running echo (and since it works outside of web2py) I have my doubts that the child process is signalling itself.

Is there some web2py limitation/configuration that causes `Popen()` requests to always fail?  If so, how can I modify my logic so that the controller (or whatever) is actually able to spawn this external process?

** EDIT:  Looks like web2py applications may not like the subprocess module.  According to a reply to [a message reply in the web2py email group](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.web2py/40437):

"You should not use subprocess in a web2py application (if you really need too, look into the admin/controllers/shell.py) but you can use it in a web2py program running from shell (web2py.py -R myprogram.py)."

I will be checking out some options based on the note here and see if any solution presents itself.

Comment: I'm having the same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501052/python-subprocess-module-failing-to-execute-bitcoind). Your answer is nice but I would like to know what could be intercepting the process with `SIGABRT` and how can I identify it?

Comment: @derrend - Honestly not sure what causes it. My guess is that it has something to do with the way that web2py hijacks the python runtime.  From what I remember look through the source (this was a while ago), web2py effectively runs a giant `exec` on your code within its own, specialized scope. I don't know the details, but maybe this scope is hostile towards `Popen`?  If you are really curious, I'd recommend the mailing list. The web2py creator is pretty active there.

Comment: @derrend - Just realized that you are on Django instead of web2py.  I'm not familiar with the Django internals, but I figure it could either be that Django operates similarly to web2py, or perhaps that there is an issue starting a subprocess from a process spun up by a webserver. For what it's worth, I was originally running my application via Apache/wsgi. Maybe that's the culprit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, the best I was able to come up with involved setting up a simple XML RPC server and call the functions from that:

*my_server.py*

```
#my_server.py
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer, SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler
from subprocess import *

proc_srvr = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:12345")

def echo_fn():
    p = Popen(("echo", "hello"), shell=False)
    ret = p.wait()
    print "Process ended with status %s" % ret
    return True  # RPC Server doesn't like to return None

def main():
    server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 12345), ErrorHandler) 
    server.register_function(echo_fn, "echo_fn")
    while True:
        server.handle_request()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

*web2py_controller.py*

```
#web2py_controller.py

def run_echo():
    proc_srvr = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:12345")
    proc_srvr.echo_fn()
```

I'll be honest, I'm not a Python nor SimpleRPCServer guru, so the overall code may not be up to best-practice standards.  However, going this route did allow me to, in effect, call a subprocess from a controller in web2py.

(Note, this was a quick and dirty simplification of the code that I have in my project.  I have not validated it is in a working state, so it may require some tweaks.)